# Is blocking a soft hit considered a block?

Tags: rules, volleyball

If team B attempts to block a ball and team A tips the ball rather than attacks the ball but the ball does come in contact with Team B, is that considered a block contact or first contact?

I would assume that it is considered a block contacct but the referee called it a 'first contact' and team B lost the point because they tried to use 3 contacts after the ball was touched at the net.